# How to create a dynamic list of buttons on MainPage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an application to scan barcode tickets. When you start the app a list of available shows has to be shown on the screen. To get all the available shows I'm using a webservice which returns me a `List<Event>`. How do I create a list of buttons with each button representing a show/event from inside the xaml.cs? When clicking the button a new page will be shown where the user can scan the tickets from that show. I'm pretty new to Xamarin.Forms and I quite don't understand how to use the paging/content views. I already searched a lot but the closest to what I need was this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=vswin

Unfortunatly it only shows how to add a certain amount of controls. And not a dynamicly generated amount.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: bind your List<Event> to a ListView, then each row of the ListView can be tapped or selected.  You don't actually need to create buttons

Comment: @Jason If I create a <ListView x:Name=lvTest> inside my xaml, why won't my code behind recognize lvTest = ...?

Comment: @Basvo: If your markup for the ListView is valid, then your page class _should_ have an `IvTest` property on it, which after the `InitializeComponents()` call in the constructor will be set to the ListView instance with that name. Then you can set the `ItemsSource` property of `IvTest` to the list of events. If you don't see that working, you should verify that the XAML is correct before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

In xaml insert a stacklayout where you want your buttons to appear. Remember you can also play whith its Orientation and Spacing properties. So:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyButtons"/>
```

Then in code-behind generate your dinamic buttons list. Put the code in constructor AFTER `InitializeComponent();` or somewhere else:

```
    var myList = new List<*Event or something*>(); //your list here
    MyButtons.Children.Clear(); //just in case so you can call this code several times np..
                foreach (var item in myList)
                {
                    var btn = new Button()
                    {
                        Text = item.*your property*, //Whatever prop you wonna put as title;
                        StyleId = item.*your ID property* //use a property from event as id to be passed to handler
                    };
                    btn.Clicked += OnDynamicBtnClicked;
                    MyButtons.Children.Add(btn);
                }
```

Add a handler:

```
private void OnDynamicBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myBtn = sender as Button;
            // who called me?
            var myId = myBtn.StyleId; //this was set during dynamic creation

            //do you stuff upon is
            switch (myId)
            {
                    case "1": //or other value you might have set as id
                        //todo
                        break;
                    default:
                        //todo
                        break;
            }

        }
```