# Xamarin Forms, I am trying to add a dynamic stack of buttons, but my app crashes when trying to launch on IOS, throwing an exception

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a stack of dynamically added buttons.

I am trying to build an app where you can scroll through a page to find a recipe you like and click the button in order to open another page that includes the ingredients and cooking instructions.

I followed this guide: [How to create a dynamic list of buttons on MainPage in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429390/how-to-create-a-dynamic-list-of-buttons-on-mainpage-in-xamarin-forms) However whenever I try to launch the app on my iphone11, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glODF.jpg)

I am really frustrated right now, as I don't know what to do. I am new to xamarin forms, so please explain to me as if I have the IQ of an orangutan.

Here is my code:

recipeList.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CUapp
{
    public class recipeList
{
    public static List<recipeModel> list;

    public recipeList()
    {
        list.Add(new recipeModel { title = "spag. Meatball", id = "1"});
        list.Add(new recipeModel { title = "page1", id = "2" });
        list.Add(new recipeModel { title = "page2", id = "3" });
    }

}
}
```

recipeModel.cs:

```
using System;
namespace CUapp
{
    public class recipeModel
    {  
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Recipes.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CUapp.Recipes"
    Title="Recipes"
    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Sharpnado.MaterialFrame;assembly=Sharpnado.MaterialFrame">

    
        <ScrollView >
            <StackLayout x:Name="buttons" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="10">
                <!--<rv:MaterialFrame x:Name="button" AcrylicGlowColor="Gray" LightThemeBackgroundColor="brown" WidthRequest="800" Style="{StaticResource AcrylicFrame}">
                <Button
                    Text="Spag. Meatballs"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                ></Button>
                </rv:MaterialFrame>-->

                

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    

</ContentPage>
```

Recipes.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CUapp
{
    public partial class Recipes : ContentPage
    {
        public Recipes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            double w = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;

            buttons.Children.Clear();
            foreach (var item in recipeList.list)
            {
                var btn = new Button()
                {
                    Text = item.title,
                    StyleId = item.id
                    };
                btn.Clicked += OnDynamicBtnClicked;
                buttons.Children.Add(btn);
            }
        }

        private async void OnDynamicBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myBtn = sender as Button;
            // who called me?
            var myId = myBtn.StyleId; //this was set during dynamic creation

            //do you stuff upon is
            switch (myId)
            {
                case "1":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SpaghettiMeatball());
                    break;

                case "2":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page_1());
                    break;

                case "3":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page_2());
                    break;
            }

        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new SpaghettiMeatball());
        }
    }
}
```

thank you so much guys!

EDIT:
Here is the "exception thrown page"
[exception thrown page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMbWX.png)

Comment: when you get an exception, click on the "show details" button and it will tell you all kinds of interesting things, like the **exact line** that is causing the exception

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect you want by using CollectionView. When the CollectionView is clicked, the clicked item information is obtained, and then sent to Page1 for display, so that there is no need to create multiple pages.

Here is the xaml code for the Recipes:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="dddd.Recipes"
Title="collectionViewTest">

   <StackLayout>
     <CollectionView  x:Name="Mycll" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Mycll_SelectionChanged">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <Label Text="{Binding title}"></Label>
             </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
     </CollectionView>
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the c# code for the Recipes:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Recipes : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<recipeModel> myC { get; set; }
    public Recipes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    
        recipeList re = new recipeList();
        myC = new ObservableCollection<recipeModel>(re.list);
        Mycll.ItemsSource = myC;
    }
    public void Mycll_SelectionChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        a = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as recipeModel;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(a));
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml code for the Page1(Details page):

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="dddd.Page1">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="xid">
        </Label>
        <Label x:Name="xtitle">
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the c# code for the Page1:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1(recipeModel recipeModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        xid.Text = recipeModel.id;
        xtitle.Text = recipeModel.title;
    }
}
```

Here is the c# code for the recipeList:

```
public class recipeList
{
    public ObservableCollection<recipeModel> list;
    public recipeList()
    {
        list = new ObservableCollection<recipeModel>
        {
            new recipeModel { title = "spag. Meatball", id = "1" },
            new recipeModel { title = "page1", id = "2" },
            new recipeModel { title = "page2", id = "3" },
        };         
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot：

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should give us more information (for example the exception message you're getting).
By the way, I can give you some hints that I think you should consider:

1. In your code you're calling `double w = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;` without using it. If current main page is null (because the main page is Recipes and your just inside its constructor) you will receive a null reference exception. You are not using the width value, so why don't you remove it?
2. You should rewrite your static list class like this in order to have some valid values:

   ```
    public class recipeList
    {
        public static List<recipeModel> list = new List<recipeModel> { 
            new recipeModel { title = "spag. Meatball", id = "1" }, 
            new recipeModel { title = "page1", id = "2" }, 
            new recipeModel { title = "page2", id = "3" } 
        };
    }
   ```
3. Be sure you have set the MainPage inside a NavigationPage before calling Navigation.PushAsync() method.
   In your App.cs you should have: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for responding to my question :D

Basically I called double w because I thought I would use it, and I should've commented it out.

I tried your third solution, to no avail sadly :(

I have updated my question to include the errors shown

Comment: Also doing MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); adds a hideous black bar at the top of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use ObservableCollection instead of List as it has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented (this will update your UI when you populate the collection)
2. Use a ListView or CollectionView in your XAML and bind your ObservableCollection to it. Check docs on which one is better for your purpose: [CollectionView and ListView differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction). You can also create the buttons in the List- or CollectionView then.

Comment: how do I do this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for your detailed answers.

Thankfully I have found a solution to my problem.

I have searched on youtube for an observableCollection tutorial which I have followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41NiKhFxYb0

And I used Classid instead of styleid, as I have learned that styleid is not bindable.

This was the first time I had ever asked a question on stack overflow, and I am impressed by the number of helpful answers you guys provided. Thanks so much for being such a helpful community :) <3